# Codeigniter with Temp Table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a query with a `Stored Procedure`. I'm able to create it and there is no problem when i running it. Here is My StoredProcedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_Penilaian
    @Nip varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

    select * INTO #tMP from historyposition where nip = ''+@Nip+'' order by approveddate desc

declare @NewPosition varchar(50), @NewPositionLast varchar(50), @ApproveDate datetime, @ApproveDateLast datetime
select top 1 @NewPositionLast = NewPosition, @ApproveDateLast=ApprovedDate from #tmp
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tMP)
BEGIN
    select top 1 @NewPosition = NewPosition, @ApproveDate=ApprovedDate from #tmp
    if (@NewPosition = @NewPositionLast)
    begin 
        set @NewPositionLast = @NewPosition 
        set @ApproveDateLast = @ApproveDate
    end 
    else
    begin
        break
    end
    delete top(1) #tMP
END
select  @NewPositionLast 'LatesUpgradePosition' , @ApproveDateLast 'LatesUpgradeDate'
END
GO
```

this how i run it

```
sp_penilaian '1500060'
```

And here is the resullt

[image]

Ok. The problem is when i'm trying to call my SP in Codeigniter.

```
$nip = '1500060';
$filt_outlet = $this->db->query("SP_Penilaian '".$nip."'")->row();
```

and then i'm trying to check my data with this

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($filt_outlet)."</pre>";
```

But i get empty data. So how to use temp table  with CodeIgniter? or if i can't use temp table can i just create table and drop it in my Stored Procedure?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: why all the complexity of that stored proc? you just want the most recently updated position and date/time of that  - just get that with a query. no temp table needed, no dynamic sql needed.  #avoid-the-rbar

Comment: well, i'm just curious why every SP that contain `#` table is not working. I'm not using this SP. I just write a query inside my PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` after `BEGIN`

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_Penilaian
    @Nip varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON; /*<--Add here*/

    select * INTO #tMP from historyposition where nip = ''+@Nip+'' order by approveddate desc

declare @NewPosition varchar(50), @NewPositionLast varchar(50), @ApproveDate datetime, @ApproveDateLast datetime
select top 1 @NewPositionLast = NewPosition, @ApproveDateLast=ApprovedDate from #tmp
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tMP)
BEGIN
    select top 1 @NewPosition = NewPosition, @ApproveDate=ApprovedDate from #tmp
    if (@NewPosition = @NewPositionLast)
    begin 
        set @NewPositionLast = @NewPosition 
        set @ApproveDateLast = @ApproveDate
    end 
    else
    begin
        break
    end
    delete top(1) #tMP
END
select  @NewPositionLast 'LatesUpgradePosition' , @ApproveDateLast 'LatesUpgradeDate'
END
GO
```

Comment: it's fix my problem. But why i need `SET NOCOUNT ON;`?

Comment: i learnt it from here [link]http://daleburnett.com/2014/01/everything-ever-wanted-know-set-nocount/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the problem lies with the actual stored procedure but with the way you ar calling it. Try:

```
$nip = '1500060';
$sp = "CALL SP_Penilaian(?)";
```

And to pass the nip to the stored procedure you can use CodeIgniter's database query funtion like so:

```
$filt_outlet = $this->db->query($sp, array('nip'=>$nip));
```